# Dump MySQL CREATE TABLE for whole schema including foreign keys (creating order)

Tags: php, mysql

What I would like to 'have' is someway to export my tables including the foreign keys. And whenever/whereever re-execute those create table queries.

The problem I am facing though is making sure the right preconditions exist per table.

if table B references A and A references C. Then first C must be created, then A and at last B.

But creating the right order is something that I do not know how to do (yet).

I am currently creating the queries this way: (not the complete code)

```
class DBManager{
    private function createSQLCreateTableDump(){
        $query = "SHOW TABLES";
        $res = $this->db->prepare($query)->fetchObjectAll();
        foreach( $res as $table){
            $this->createSQLCreateTableQuery(current(get_object_vars($table)));
        }
    }

    private function createSQLCreateTableQuery($tableName){
        $query = "SHOW CREATE TABLE {$tableName}";
        $res = $this->db->prepare($query)->fetchObjectOnce();

        return $res->{"Create Table"};
    }
}
```

As a reference, `$this->db` is a class named Database which extends PDO.
`fetchObjectOnce` and `fetchObjectAll` returns each row returned as an object. The first argument (which I am not using here) specifies the class type returned. Else stdClass is used.

`current(get_object_vars($table))` is used to get the first column returned. Because the column names differ per database used. This seemed the fastest/easiest way.

The problem with this method is that some tables with constraints will be created before the constraint can be created.

***the question***: What would be a good solution to this problem?

Just thought of this: (which I will try to work out).
I can get the constraints themself from the informatino_schema.table_constraints and key_column_usage tables. Thus I can create a tree of dependancies. Will see how far I can come that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I've answered my own question and provided an example:

http://pastebin.com/5dg6B0ZF

it is not the cleanest of my work, but it works so far.

it creates two temporary arrays.

One holding the references per table, the other the queries.
I am using table names as keys for the arrays for easy searching.

I won't accept my own answer till somewhere tomorrow to see if someone else comes up with a better solution.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: This is very complex, maybe it works. But what's wrong with doing what mysqldump does? The "magic" is just turning off foreign keys in the dump.

Comment: Well, I would say, try it yourself with the code provided (and alter the database class part of course). The thing is, I need those constraints. One way or another. The point is is that I can develop on my private machine. Alter the database. Do a dump, that makes an array of queries in PHP. And then on another machine I can just run all those queries and voila, I replicated >the structure< of the database. This will also work on the target environment of course.

Comment: Yeah, mysqldump does that for you without writing commplex PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is to invoke mysqldump, which does exactly what you suggested.

If for some reason, you feel that you can't invoke mysqldump (which is typically installed on all mysql client systems), then you can inspect its source and determine how it does it.

As far as I know, mysqldump disables foreign keys while doing some operations, to avoid dependencies during table creation.

Recreating the behaviour of mysqldump is nontrivial and difficult to do correctly, I strongly advise you to invoke mysqldump instead.

Comment: mysqldump does no magic at all - it just uses 


/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;

before importing.

Comment: I don't really think I can invoke that on the shared webserver('s) that I use for hosting my app. Also I don't really want to dump the data, only the table information/create queries. Nonetheless I will take a look at it.

Comment: The widely used phpmyadmin tool has the same functionality

Comment: @MarkR I've provided my own answer. Let me know what you think :)